# How to increment letter combinations in c++ beyond 'z'?

Tags: c++, excel, char, increment

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet, and I have to use only one type of formula for a huge amount of data. Since in the formula the only necessary changes concern letters, I was wondering if there is a way to make a program that increments them following the Excel columns order (A, B, C...Z; AA, AB, AC...AZ; BA, BB, BC...BZ).

In my case, I would need to increment letters each time by five, so here is the kind of code I'm trying to obtain:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 char x = 'B';
 char y = 'E';
 for (int z = 1; z < 2255; z++) {
   cout << "=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(" << x << "1:" << y << "1,ROW(" << x << "1:" << x << "100)-ROW(" << x << "1),)))" << endl;
   x = x + 5;
   y= y + 5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course it won't work because it goes over 'z', but still, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**General solution descriptions**

**Solution 1:** Create base-26 system itself:

Assume that you have 26 letters. So first lets make 26 number system. We use 1 byte for each digit. We create an array of digits, and then we need to adjust sometimes when adding exceeds 26.

Let's assume your current digit is 25. We add 7 to it, and then we need to handle the overflow, assuming 256 (1 byte) as maximum, and our digit limit is 26. Hence the adjustment  will be  `256-26=230`. (We do this calculation on short (16 bits), so we get overflow at `26+7=33 -> 33+230=263`. Therefore, the higher byte will be 1, the lower byte  will be 7.)

Having calculated the overflow threshold (above it was 1), we can then add it to next coming digit and do the same if overflow occur.

Finally, for display we just add 65 ('A') to each of the two bytes. Our last byte will be '\0' null terminating so we could turn it into a string.

**Solution 2** Perform all calculations and then convert it to a 26-base number:

In this case,

```
number/26 = x
```

and

```
remainder r1 = (number%26)
```

We store r1 to a byte.

```
x/26 = x1
```

and

```
remainder r2 = (x%26)
```

We store r2 to the next byte.

```
x1/26 = x2
```

and

```
remainder r3 = (x%26)
```

We store r3 to the next byte. We get a string `r3 r2 r1 '\0'` and then add 65  'A' to each byte.

Comment: Why the awkward formatting? Why block quote for ordinary text? I am happy to edit this, but I wonder if there is any intention behind the format.

Comment: You may want to look at the Markdown source (by clicking `edit` without actually editing anything) to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
x = (x + 5 > 'Z' ? x + 5 - 'Z' + 'A' : x + 5);
y = (y + 5 > 'Z' ? y + 5 - 'Z' + 'A' : y + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two nested loops, both from `'A'` to `'Z'`, then just append both characters together. Put the results in a vector.

To get the single-letter `'A'` to `'Z'`, add them to the vector before the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as one option, create a new data type consisting of two characters (something like `std::pair<char,char>` and define arithmetics for this.

However, I think it would be simpler to keep using `int` (or `unsigned int`) for the counting and arithmetic, and define a function `to_col_heading` which translates the integer into a one/two-character column heading for Excel:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>

/* This is the function that performs
   the transformation. */    
std::string to_col_heading(unsigned i)
{
  if (i > 26+26*26)
    throw std::overflow_error
      ("Value too large for transformation into Excel column heading.");

  char char1 = 'A' + (i / 26) - 1;
  char char2 = 'A' + (i % 26);

  if (char1 < 'A')
    return std::string(&char2,&char2 + 1);
  else
    return std::string(&char1,&char1 + 1) + char2;
}

int main()
{
  std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out(std::cout,", ");
  for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < 26+26*26 ; i += 5)
    *out = to_col_heading(i);

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A, F, K, P, U, Z, AE, AJ, AO, AT, AY, BD, BI, BN, BS, BX, CC, CH, CM, CR, CW, DB, DG, DL, DQ, DV, EA, EF, EK, EP, EU, EZ, FE, FJ, FO, FT, FY, GD, GI, GN, GS, GX, HC, HH, HM, HR, HW, IB, IG, IL, IQ, IV, JA, JF, JK, JP, JU, JZ, KE, KJ, KO, KT, KY, LD, LI, LN, LS, LX, MC, MH, MM, MR, MW, NB, NG, NL, NQ, NV, OA, OF, OK, OP, OU, OZ, PE, PJ, PO, PT, PY, QD, QI, QN, QS, QX, RC, RH, RM, RR, RW, SB, SG, SL, SQ, SV, TA, TF, TK, TP, TU, TZ, UE, UJ, UO, UT, UY, VD, VI, VN, VS, VX, WC, WH, WM, WR, WW, XB, XG, XL, XQ, XV, YA, YF, YK, YP, YU, YZ, ZE, ZJ, ZO, ZT, ZY,
```

---

To support up to 3 (alphabetical) digits for the column headings, the function below works. It handles the first 26 values completely separately to simplify the calculation of the rest. I've also introduced some static constants to deal in a more consistent way with the powers of 26. For three digits, you need 26<sup>0</sup>, 26<sup>1</sup> and 26<sup>2</sup>, but the system can be expanded to cover any number of digits.

I am sure there a ways to optimize this for speed; this was not the focus here.

```
std::string to_col_heading(unsigned i)
{
  const static unsigned pow1 = 26;
  const static unsigned pow2 = 26*26;
  const static unsigned max  = pow1 + pow2 + 26 * pow2;

  if (i < pow1)
    {
      char c = 'A' + i % pow1;
      return std::string(&c,&c+1);
    }

  if (i > max)
    throw std::overflow_error
      ("Value too large for transformation into Excel column heading.");

  i -= pow1;
  char char1 = 'A' + (i / pow2) - 1;
  char char2 = 'A' + (i%pow2) / pow1;
  char char3 = 'A' + i % pow1;

  if (char1 < 'A')
    return std::string(&char2,&char2 + 1) + char3;
  else
    return std::string(&char1,&char1 + 1) + char2 + char3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would need 3 digits, is it possible with this method?

Comment: Because the last column I have is under the letter 'PQL'.

Comment: Yes, sure. The same logic can be expanded to any number of characters.

Comment: And, sorry for the stupid question, what should be changed in the code above in order to do that?

Comment: @user2499266 I've implemented a version that supports three alphabetical digits. But let me just say I hope you do not misuse Stackoverflow as a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're trying to produce can be viewed as a base-27 number, using the characters 'A' through 'Z' as the 26 digits. It is a *little* unusual, in that 'A' is really '0', but when you get to a two-digit number, it's "AA", (where a normal two-digit would be `BA` -- i.e., just like the next number after 9 is `10`). We have to do a fairly minor adjustment to compensate for that oddity.

You can do the counting with a normal `int` (or whatever) and then convert to base 27 when needed. Since I don't think it supports more columns than that, I've restricted this version to 2 digits, though extending to more would be fairly trivial:

```
std::string to_excel_column(int input) { 
    int digit1 = input % 26;
    int digit2 = input / 26;

    std::string result;
    if (input > 26)
        result.push_back(digit2 + 'A' - 1);
    result.push_back(digit1 + 'A');
    return result;
}
```